# Pygments HTML table with line numbers - horizontal scrollbar for the code cell

Tags: html, css, pygments

I'm using Python implementation of Markdown with `codehilite` and `lineos` option. It produces a code like this:

```html
<table class="codehilitetable">
    <tr>
        <td class="linenos">
            <div class="linenodiv">
                <pre>1
                     2</pre>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="code"><div class="codehilite"><pre>
            <span class="k">def</span>
            <span class="nf">func</span>
            <span class="p">(</span>
            <span class="n">n</span>
            <span class="p">):</span>
            <span class="k">return</span>
            <span class="n">n</span> 
            <span class="o">**</span>
            <span class="mi">2</span>
            <span class="o">+</span>
            <span class="mi">3</span>
            <span class="o">*</span>
            <span class="n">n</span>
            <span class="o">+</span>
            <span class="mi">1</span>
        </pre></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is a table with one row and two cells; first cell is for line numbers and second is cell is for actual code. The contents of each cell are inside a `div` and `pre` element and `span` elements are used for syntax coloring.

I would like to display a horizontal scrollbar in case a line of code is too long, but I'm having problems, because it's a table.

Ideally I'd want the scrollbar just on the code cell (`td.code`), but this only works if set width of the table to 100%, which makes both cells long 50%. I want the line-number cell (`td.linenos`) to be just as long as it's required for the actual line-numbers to be shown.

Here's my current CSS:

```
pre, code { overflow:auto; }

table.codehilitetable { table-layout: fixed; white-space: nowrap; width:100%; }
```

If this is not possible, then I'd like to have a scrollbar on the whole row (`tr`). But the above code doesn't work on table rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
.codehilite{
          width:100%;
          height: auto;
          overflow: auto;
        }
```

That will make the div inside the code table cell have a horizontal scrollbar if needed.

Comment: I think that's closer than I've gotten, but now `td.code` cell is as long as a too-long line unless I set width of the table to 100%, which again messes up the cells. And scrollbar is shown only if I set width of `.codehilite` to something less than 100%.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Is there a reason you can't set a specific width on the table?

Answer (score 0):

Not all of this is necessary, but some of this made it work.

for some reason making the `pre` container really small made it scroll properly.

```
.codehilite pre, .codehilitetable .linenodiv pre {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
table.docutils, table.docutils tbody, table.docutils tr, table.docutils td {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.codehilitetable td.linenos, .codehilitetable .linenodiv pre {
    padding: 0;
    border-right: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
}
.codehilitetable td.code {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
.codehilitetable td.code .codehilite{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.codehilitetable td.code .codehilite pre {
    width: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```